# Calling a method from another application via code injection?

Tags: c#, c++, linux, code-injection

I have an application that runs on a locked down linux machine.

Its signature checked from boot so I cannot swap the application for a patched version.

However, I can run other applications from the command line.

Is there anyway that I can write an application to call a certain method within another application currently running? Maybe via code injection?

I do have the source code of this other application.

Comment: What software are you trying to hack?

Comment: Have a look at the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10534841/createremotethread-in-linux)

Comment: This is pretty vague.  You want to call a single *method* from the signed, unchangeable program from another?  You list a bunch of languages here, but in this case it's pretty important to identify the language of the protected program you're trying to call.

Comment: If you don't have access to the machine then you trying to hack it. Also, if your trying to hack be smart and pose your question as security question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have root access, or you started the program you want to run inside, I guess you could use debug functions (such as ptrace) to access the memory inside the protected application. If you don't have root access or are yourself the owner of the application, I would hope (and believe) that you can't do what you want, since that would make the whole operating system very unsafe!