# Attach to already running JVM

Tags: java, c++, jvm, java-native-interface

Is there a way to attach to an already running JVM?

For example, in JNI you can use `JNI_CreateJavaVM` to create a VM and run a jar and inspect all its classes..

However, if the jar is already running, I cannot find a way to attach to its JVM and communicate with its classes or get its `env` pointer..

Another problem is that if the jar loads my native library (.dll) and I want to create a JVM inside the .dll, I cannot.. Nor can I attach the jar's current JVM either without the jar calling my function..

Example on the Java side:

```
class Foo
{
    static {loadLibrary("Foo")}
}
```

on the C++ side:

```
void Foo()
{
    //CreateJVM
    //Attach to the current process..
    //Call function from the jar that loaded me.
}
```

This cannot be done without the jar calling `Foo` first.

Any ideas? Is there no way to get the current JVM or to attach to it or an external jvm instance?

Comment: Is this for windows or linux or some other OS?  Which C debugger/IDE are you using?

Comment: I might be missing smth, but can't you just open up debug port and attach to it? In the debugger hit pause VM and expect everything?

Comment: I'm using Codeblocks and I'm on Windows.  I'm not sure what you mean by open up the debugger and hit pause..

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames Let me know if you managed to use my answer. It works fine.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes you can.

**1)**  Inject a DLL in the process hosting the JVM (eg, `java.exe`, or `javaw.exe`, or `iexplore.exe`). A common injection technique is to use [SetWindowsHookEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990.aspx)

**2)** In the DLL, get the module handle of the `jvm.dll` using `GetModuleHandle`

**3)** Get the address of the `JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs` function, using `GetProcAddress`

**4)** Call the function and, if successfull, attach your thread to the first JVM found, using the `AttachCurrentThread` function pointer from the `JavaVM` struture.

**5)** Done.

Usefull link: [The Invocation API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html)

Comment: Yes! This works :D I didn't use `SetWindowsHook`. Instead I just used the `CreateThread` and `LoadLibrary` combination for injecting. Nevertheless, it works =) I am happy!

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames Happy coding! (and beware the JNI memory leaks :-)

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames Side note: with `SetWindowsHookEx`, you can choose to attach to the "GUI" thread. It may matter.

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot. JNI allow for exactly two models:

- Your non-Java program creates the JVM.
- You Java program invokes a native method.

If you need to communicate in other cases, you will need to use some other mechanism. Web services are one straightforward approach.

Comment: You can inject a dynamic link library in a running java process, and attach to the JVM. See my answer. Works fine on Windows.

Comment: Works on linux as well, [just a little different of course](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14986308/21851535)