# Get FilePath of Windows Explorer Context Menu (Right-click menu) to Java

Tags: java, java-native-interface, contextmenu, filepath

let's suppose that I have created and added a new entry to the Windows explorer right-click menu (context menu) by adding a registry entry that points to a .exe written in C++ that just reads and returns the filename of the clicked file.

Is it possible to get this filename to an already running Java app?

I thought of using JNI but is it possible to call a method of an already running Java app from a native C++ program?

Does anybody have another idea how to solve this? Is it possible to have a pure Java solution?

Many thanks.

Edit: Is it possible to call an existing method of an already running JVM? Then I could create a C++ program that listen for right-clicks and register that .exe with a registry entry for the contextmenu. Inside the C++ program, I could call a dll that injects into an already running JVM. The dll could call a Java method and commits the clicked filepath to Java. Would that be a possibility?

Comment: Ok, I've achieved the following: I've created a C++ program that is linked with a regsitry entry (contextmenu / right-click menu). If a user clicks a file, the filepath is transfered (command line arguments) to the program. Inside the program, a dll is loaded and the filepath is tranferred to a defined method inside the dll that just prints the filepath. What I would like to achieve now is to call a method of an already running Java program (inside the dll) and transfer the filepath to the Java method instead of printing it. Do you have any advice? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could connect to an already running Java program through a socket connection, or store values to a database of some kind that both your C++ application and Java application can access.

Besides my suggestions, [here's a stackoverflow post that talks about communicating to a Java program already running without the Java program making the initial communication](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22450463/3352285).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. It is a local Java program therefore I think that a socket connection is not the best possibility to solve that. Isn't there another way to detect a right-click on a file and get the clicked filename to Java (Windows 7 64bit)? Is the injection method the only possibility?

Comment: Sorry I don't know. I don't know the API's Microsoft made available for Windows Explorer but I'd imagine that any solution has to start in native code, even a Java solution would technically have part of the solution still using JNI or some other native code means I would think.